# Simple XML parsing throws Object reference error

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq, linq-to-xml

How can i parse the following XML File?

```
<Website.com xmlns="">
  <Matc>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Date>2013-11-27T18:00:00+01:00</Date>
    <Home>Moscow</Home>
  </Matc>
  <Matc>
    <Id>2</Id>
  </Matc>
</Website.com>
```

I tried the following code but it throws that `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error since `[Date]` and `Home` are missing at the second part of the XML file.

```
 Dim ns As XNamespace = ""
 Dim matcFromXml = From m In xDoc.Descendants("Matc") Select New With { _
   .Id = IIf(m.Element(ns + "Id") Is Nothing, 0, m.Descendants(ns + "Id").FirstOrDefault().Value), _
   .[Date] = IIf(m.Element(ns + "Date") Is Nothing, DateTime.Now, UtcToDateTime(m.Descendants(ns + "Date").FirstOrDefault().Value)), _
   .Home = IIf(m.Element(ns + "Home") Is Nothing, "", m.Descendants(ns + "Home").FirstOrDefault().Value)}
```

How can i fix that? What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is highly recommended to cast an `XElement` to `Integer` or `DateTime?`, instead of reading the `Value` property, for precisely this reason. Also, consider using the `If` coalescing operator.

```
Dim matcFromXml = From m In xDoc.Descendants("Matc") Select New With { _
    .Id = CInt(m.Descendants(ns + "Id").FirstOrDefault()),
    .[Date] = If(CType(m.Descendants(ns + "Date").FirstOrDefault(), Date?), DateTime.Now),
    .Home = If(CStr(m.Descendants(ns + "Home").FirstOrDefault()),"")}
```

If there is no `Id` element, then using plain `CInt` for the `Id` will cause an error. Instead, use `If` and `CType`:

```
    .Id = If(CType(m.Descendants(ns + "Id").FirstOrDefault(),Integer?),0),
```